# a*(x^2) + b*x +c equation in r

Tags: r, equations, linear-discriminant

I've been given this equation, and I'm asked to create a program where the solutions for

```
a*(x^2) + b*x +c = 0
```

are given like this:

1) if D > 0, 2 solutions are:

```
x1 = (-b -sqrt(D))/2a and x2= (-b+ sqrt(D))/2a
```

2)if D = 0 , 1 'double' solution':

```
x1 = -b/2a
```

3)if D < 0, no true solution

where D the linear discriminant = b^2 - 4*a*

I have absolutely no idea in what to try, the only thing i did was try to define D:

```
 `D <- b^2 - 4*a*c`
```

But i get an error

`Error: object 'b' not found`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: illegible. Structure your question in paragraphs (empty lines) to make this readable.

Comment: You cannot expect R interpreter to recognize b when the b is not declared as a variable or fed as an argument via a function.

Comment: What you want to do is write a function - so you actually need to write one. Read up on writing functions in R. then what you did is a good start

Comment: @SerhatCevikel how do I define it as an actual value (as well as a,c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
# calculate the real root(s) of a quadratic polynomial
# coefficients of which are given as aa, bb and cc
quadratic_roots <- function(aa = 1, bb = 2, cc = 1)
{
    # calculate the discriminant
    disc <- bb^2 - 4 * aa * cc

    if (disc == 0) # if1, single root
    {
        return(-bb / (2 * aa))
    }   
    else
    {
        if (disc > 0) # if2, two roots
        {
            root1 <- (-bb - sqrt(disc)) / (2 * aa)
            root2 <- (-bb + sqrt(disc)) / (2 * aa)
            return(c(root1, root2))

        }
        else # no real roots, return NA
        {
            return(NA)
        }   
    }   
}
```

Note that r-base has a built-in polyroot, however it will automatically return complex roots so will not serve your purpose.

And why I used aa, bb and cc instead of a, b and c:

Because "c" coincides with a very important built in function. It is not good practice to use built-in function names for custom object names.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really helpful!
I have a couple of questions though,
is it not supposed to show c(root1,root2) when i run
disc>0 ?
When I do that it returns :
Error: object 'disc' not found
and when i run :
disc <- bb^2 - 4 * aa * cc
it gives : 
Error: object 'bb' not found

(also, what do the numbers given to aa,bb,cc mean?
i know i may be asking some obvious stuff but its the first time i actually experiment with r an programming)

Comment: 'disc' is not an argument of thfunstion described in the answer. You have to provide values for 'aa', 'bb' and 'cc'.

Comment: and how do i do that, i mean they are supposed to be numbers in the actual equation, how do i value them?

Comment: It is better for you to view the "Writing Your Own Functions" section of "An Introduction to R" manual at https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions